# PHP/MySQL query ignored if 'action' is set in form

Tags: php, sql, forms, input

I basically have:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="text" type="text" value="Insert text here" size="20"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My PHP code then checks if submit is pressed:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $newDbValue = $_POST['text'];
    $sql = ("
        UPDATE `pseudo_tableName` 
        SET TEXT = '".$newDbValue."' 
        WHERE name = 'pseudo_fieldName' LIMIT 1
    ");
    //SQL-query run by php function in separate class.
}
```

And as I understand it, if the form data is submitted it sends the user back to **index.php**?

But what mine does is it **fails to update with new values** and sends me back to index.php as if there was nothing wrong!

If I leave `action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>"` or `action=""` in the form, **it updates when I reload the page** (not F5 - click in address-line and hit enter).

***What I want this to be:***
I hit submit, and it updates the DB, sends me to index.php.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your code looks correct; I wonder if you are being bitten by cache.  Try including `echo date("H:i:s", now()).'<pre>'.print_r($POST,true).'</pre>';` to make sure the page you're seeing is actually the most recent version from the server including your form data.  By the way, `action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" ` and `action=""` will generate the same output, you probably mean `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`

Comment: What is the name of the script that contains this code?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `action=""` (making you reload the page and using same file you have you `if` in) in your form and change your `if` to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $newDbValue = $_POST['text'];
    $sql = ("
            UPDATE `pseudo_tableName` 
            SET TEXT = '".$newDbValue."' 
            WHERE name = 'pseudo_fieldName' LIMIT 1
    ");
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I get an error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /index.php:14) in /index.php on line 117` ... Line 14 is where my `<?php` tag starts. Line 117 is where my `header` code was just added.

Comment: @Kristian so, put this form handler BEFORE header adding code.

Answer (score 1):

All `<form>` elements require the `action` attribute.  What you're describing probably means your PHP script isn't detecting the form data and thus isn't making the necessary changes to your MySQL database.  The reasons behind this may depend on the browser you're using; to my understanding, if you press Enter (keyboard) the submit button `value` isn't included in the form (this is said to allow multiple submit buttons with different value and perform the correct function).

If I were you, I'd check for the actual text input in the form, not the button.

```
<?php
// check 'text' exists and make sure it isn't blank.
if(isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text']!='') {
  // do MySQL updating here.
  header("Location: index.php"); // send back to index.php after updating.
}
?>
```

Because the most efficient method to redirect is to use `header();` you're required to write your PHP form-checking script *before* the HTML form (because headers can't be send half-way through the actual document) so maybe at the top of the page before sending the HTML, additionally that way you can control what HTML is sent based on the processed data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Unfortunately I can't put the **if** php-check in the top of the document. Imagine a normal html file. On this page, lists/links/input fields/buttons will be added depending on what you click on. Example: i choose to edit the first page on my site. that adds `?table=firstPage` to my url and echo's the elements (columns) on the page. I can choose what element to edit with a link next to it. that add `field=firstField` to the url (now it's `index.php?table=firstPage&field=firstField`. So when im edit'ing a field, I want it to check when I click submit. Not in the start:)

Comment: @KristianB id you're not experienced in web programming, the best way would be to make a separate form handler page, and make it in the way mentioned by Marwelln. All other answers are just useless chatter, from dudes ho understands no more than you are.

Comment: `form` doesnt require the `action` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-action

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['text']) AND !empty($_POST['text'])) {
        // ...
    }
?>
```

Instead of the other input?

The action='index.php' will send you back to index.php, so be sure that your PHP is above the form (and your HTML, for that matter). I also gues that you have set up your mysql_connect and you mysql_query functions.

Do you have error_reporting in php.ini on? What does the MySQL query result set say when you var_dump() the variable?

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query($newDbValue));
    var_dump($sql);
?>
```

That could really help you out.

The "cannot send header information -  headers alredy sent" is because you have characters sent to the browser before the redirect() function - nothing can be sent to the browser (even whitespace!) if you're gonna use that, so be sure that the first thing in the document is your ?> tag, and your file encoding is UTF-8, not UTF-16 BOM or something crazy like that.

Comment: My input fields and buttons are controlled by `?table=` and `&field` URL-parameters... And it runs entirely inside a PHP-tag. If I put my `if(isset($_POST[$fieldName]))` in the very start if the PHP-code, it won't even run (because the value of the fields aren't set until the very end of the code. `var_dump($sql);` returned `bool(true)`... Dunno if it was what you meant.

Comment: @Kristian I meant that if you're gonna use the redirect function, put your PHP code first or it will give you that error, and always check if the variable exists and if it has values in everything (so your code always runs). If `var_dump($sql)` returned true, then the database SHOULD have been updated.